# to_csv() writes values with additional fractions

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am using `to_csv()` method to write my data frame into a **.csv** file. I have a variable called `emotion` which refers to a data frame, and I am using `to_csv()` like this;

```
 emotion.to_csv(file_name,encoding='utf-8', index = False) 
 # file_name holds a string of a full path of the file which is intended to create
```

There are over 15.000 rows of data in this data frame, and when I open to check the .csv file which is created by `to_csv` method, most of the rows look fine. But there are few exceptions. You can see a chunk of rows from the **.csv** file below;

> 2.8641,0.2737,38.18,73,97,291664
>   3.1672,0.2688,38.21,73,97,291667
>   3.4115,0.2786,38.11,73,97,291672
>   3.3675,0.2737,38.18,73,97,291675
>   **3.1719999999999997**,0.2737,38.02,73,97,291678
>   2.7761,0.2737,38.15,73,97,291682
>   2.39,0.2688,38.18,73,97,291685
>   2.0674,0.2835,38.11,73,97,291688

As I pointed out above with the **bold** font on the dataframe values, **3.1719999999999997** has an additional fractions. In the original data, it should be something like **3.171**. Could you help me to overcome this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When handling floating points, you will often see these small differences. The precision of your CPU is limited. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html for info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

*to_csv* has this nice *float_format* keyword argument that you can set.

```
emotion.to_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8', index=False, float_format="%.3f")
```

Comment: I edited my code with your advice, but it didn't affect the output. There are still some values with long fractions.

Comment: Actually when I tried it again, I figured out that all of the floated numbers were restricted by 3 fractions. But I catched few exceptions, it looks kinda a leakage, because these values which did not obey to the float_format restriction are also looking like they are not belong to that row. I am pretty confused how it could happen.

Comment: Anyways, I think it works pretty well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a cast made by pandas when extracting the values from your csv.
If you want to limit the numbers of digits displayed by the dataframe you can use:

```
 pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.3f}'.format
```

This will limit the numbers of digits to 3.

Comment: Will it limit the numbers for the .csv file as well?

Comment: This will change **all** pandas output, not just the csv export.